# select the element not equal `#text`

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, mustache

After use mustache render I try to get the dom just append, how do I select only `li.data`?
or How to make mustache return `appendedDom` not include `#text`?

```
..
var html = Mustache.to_html(this.template.data, response);
var appendedDom = $(html).appendTo(this.el.container);

console.log(appendedDom);


>> console.log
<li class=​"data">​…​</li>​
#text
```

I tried `$(appendedDom+'.data')` this not work ,
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object].data

```
  console.log($(appendedDom+'.data'));
```

Comment: How about using `$(appendedDom).find('.data-control-list').each( ... );`?

Comment: I tried but appendedDom is [<li class=​"data">​…​</li>​,
#text] not child element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `appendedDom` is just a set of elements, so you should be able to filter that:

```
$(appendedDom).filter('.data-control-list')
```